# What Genus Is This Ant Queen?

Tags: species-identification, ant

I believe she is either Lasius or Formica, but I am an amateur so thanks for any help. This queen is completely black and gray, with a gaster that kind of looks like the stone Tiger Eye but gray. There is no red or brown on her. She’s approximately 1.5 cm long and I found her in central Minnesota. She laid eggs overnight after being caught. I know the photo is terrible thanks to my phone but it was the best one I got of her. [image]